# ViewModel Initialized twice with BottomNavigationView switching

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an MVVMCross Android app with BottomNavigationView where in MainActivity OnCreate method I build fragments list, navigate to view models matched them and open first fragment

async OnCreate():

```
BuildFragmentsList();

if (_firstTimeCreated)
{
    _firstTimeCreated = false;
    await ViewModel.ShowInitialViewModelsCommand.ExecuteAsync();
}

LoadFragment(Resource.Id.menu_first);
```

BuildFragmentsList():

```
private void BuildFragmentsList()
        {
            MvxFragment firstFragment = FirstFragment.NewInstance();
            MvxFragment secondFragment = SecondFragment.NewInstance();

            fragments.Add(firstFragment);
            fragments.Add(secondFragment);
        }
```

ShowInitialViewModelsCommand():

```
private async Task ShowInitialViewModelsCommandExecute()
{
    await NavigationService.Navigate<FirstViewModel>();
    await NavigationService.Navigate<SecondViewModel>();

    IsInitialized = true;
}
```

LoadFragment():

```
private void LoadFragment(int id)
{
    try
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case Resource.Id.menu_first:
                        SwitchFragment(0);
                        break;
            case Resource.Id.menu_second:
                        SwitchFragment(1);
                        break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {exception.Message}");
        Crashes.TrackError(exception);
    }
}
```

SwitchFragment():

```
private void SwitchFragment(int pos)
        {
            if (fragments.Count > 0)
                SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                    .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragments[pos])
                    .Commit();
        }
```

I don't understand why both my ViewModels initialized twice, first when `ShowInitialViewModelsCommand` called and when I select it on `BottomNaviagtionView`.
In this case when I navigate to Second View Model it Initialized one more time and load content again
All next switches pass without calling `Initialize` method

Comment: I don't understand why you are creating instances of the fragments yourself _and_ using the `NavigationService` to navigate to the ViewModel.

Using `NavigationService` will _also_ create an instance of the Fragment using the Presentation Attributes you have provided on it to determine where to show it.

Comment: @Cheesebaron right you are! Thank you. Creating new instances of Fragments aren't necessary. I just find it by tag